# implemention of "Sum" calss with Dunder in Python

Tags: python-3.x, class

I need help,
I want to implement "Chain" Class in python with the following features:

```
>>> Chain(2.5)(2)(2)(2.5) # sum
9
>>> Chain(3)(1.5)(2)(3) # sum
9.5

>>> Chain(64) == 64
True

>>> Chain('Alex')('Smith')('is')('the')('best.') # concat with space
'Alex Smith is the best.'

>>> Chain('abc')('defg') == 'abc defg'
True
```

throw Exception when:

```
>>> Chain('Alex')(5) # raising exception with the following message
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
Exception: invalid operation

>>> Chain(9)([1, 2]) # raising exception with the following message
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
Exception: invalid operation
```

```
class Chain:
    def __init__(self,n):
        self.Sum = n

    def __call__(self,nums):
        

    def __repr__(self):
        pass

    def __eq__(self,other):
        return type(self) == type(other)
```

Comment: Can you describe in two short sentences what should happen if someone tries `Chain(<some number>)(2)`. I think you might find an initial implementation for `__call__` falls out nicely.

Comment: After you have an initial implementation of `__call__` that works for numbers, can you see how to handle the case if the provided input was a string rather than a number? Give an implementation a try and post it here. If you do, others will join in and help you finish it.

Comment: Thank you for your time. We can pass numbers or strings to class and not both of them or arrays of numbers or array of strings! I search about __call__ and Duder but I can't find example of passing some inputs to class! In fact I don't know how to write code of __call__ ,__repr__ and __equ__ functions.

Answer (score 0):

This should work with lists or any other object that has a `__iadd__` method. I'm not sure if the items in an array should all be the same object for this assignment. Otherwise, you'll have implement it.

```
class Chain:
    def __init__(self, n):
        self.sum = n

    def __call__(self, item):
        try:
            if isinstance(item, str):
                self.sum += ' ' + item
            else:
                self.sum += item
        except TypeError:
            raise Exception('invalid operation')
        return self
    
    def __repr__(self):
        return repr(self.sum)

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.sum == other
```